# define an array which its elements are object in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to define an array which its elements are object in java and i can use for ex this method:
`public void add(Object elem);`

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Objecttype objects= new Objecttype [initial size]
```

Why you  want to use arrays. go for ArrayList in which you don't bother to define your initial size also it provides its own add method

Answer (score 2):

A literal object array is defined as any other array.

```
Object[] objects = new Object[10];
```

Though, more likely, you are looking for something like `ArrayList`

```
List<Object> object = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Which will give you the `.add` functionality because it's a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Defining an array of objects is just like defining any other array

```
Object[] objectList = new Object[MAX_LIMIT];
for(int i=0;i<objectList.length;i++){
   objectList[i] = new ANY_DATA_TYPE();
}
```